# Looking for name/author of a book series with a lottery

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to find the name/author of a series of books that I read a long time ago.  I don't remember if they were any good or not.  Or whether they were well known or not.
The protagonist of the first book was a young girl who ended up a slave on earth simply by being an orphan.  She wins a lottery which enables her to buy her way to freedom and is subsequently taken off planet by a family of matriarchal clones who turn out to be related to her.  She hooks up with a former military officer turned pirate and they eventually free all the government slaves on earth.
I think the last couple of books may involve alien contact, but I may be mixing them up in my mind with some other series.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214392/space-opera-book-series-similar-to-the-seafort-saga (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 8):

F. M Busby's [Rissa Kerguelen](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2859143-rissa-kerguelen) and related series.

Most of Earth's population lives in Total Welfare centers, administered by the soulless United Energy and Transport corporation. Young Rissa wins the lottery, and, before she is cheated of her winnings, manages to escape offworld with Tregare, the space pirate and rebel.

This part of the saga was also published as three books; *Young Rissa*, *Rissa and Tregare*, and *The Long View*.
Additional novels include ["The Holzein Dynasty"](http://www.goodreads.com/series/54415) (the matriarchal clones) series: *Star Rebel*, *Rebel's Quest*, *The Alien Debt*, and *Rebel's Seed*.

Comment: Thank you.  I just could not think of the name of it.  And when I tried looking, I could not find anything that sounded like it.